# PUN 2 Player respawns on every client join

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I'm having this problem where players will respawn at spawn points every time a new player joins the room. Each player should only be moved to a spawnpoint every time they join a room. This does happen and it works. It also happens in a respawn RPC, but that isn't called until a player has already died. If any new player joins and spawns, any existing players are teleported to a spawnpoint (as if it is their first time joining). I've tried checking for local photon views, but that doesn't work. I've tried figuring out where the respawn comes from, but I can't pinpoint it. It seems that *each players' Start() function runs twice*, but that doesn't make any sense. Any ideas why this happens?

Player Start function:

```
void Start()
        {
            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                SetPlayerTeam(gameInst.specString);
                transform.position = GameManager.instance.spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, GameManager.instance.spawnPoints.Length)].position;
                transform.rotation = GameManager.instance.spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, GameManager.instance.spawnPoints.Length)].rotation;
            }
        }
```

Player Respawn RPC

```
void RespawnRPC()
        {
            SetRagdoll(false);

            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                transform.position = GameManager.instance.spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, GameManager.instance.spawnPoints.Length)].position;
                transform.rotation = GameManager.instance.spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, GameManager.instance.spawnPoints.Length)].rotation;

                if (!playerProperties.ContainsKey("state"))
                {
                    playerProperties.Add("state", "alive");
                }
                playerProperties["state"] = "alive";
                PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.SetCustomProperties(playerProperties);
            }

            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are buffering this RespawnRPC call? that would explain.

RPC can only be called by you, so put also a debug where you actually call this RespawnRPC, this will probably help as well checking that your code is not sending more than you expect.

Comment: The respawn RPC does not get called unless a player is hit with a certain raycast from another player. The raycast is only called when a player is clicking, which works. I tried putting debugs in the start function and in the respawn rpc, and it looks like the Start function is called _twice_ on the first player (which is what causes the respawn to run twice). I'm not sure why it does this, as I disable the remote player's script during their awake function. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post this question on Photon forum and link it here, stack overflow is not a good format for long discussion, then we can properly debug your issue. But by the loo0k of it, it seems indeed a problem that is unrelated to pun per say, if your rpc is called twice, maybe posting on Unity forum and UA would help as well

Comment: https://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/15364/player-respawns-on-every-client-join 
I have this post that I already made a couple of days ago. I added some edits similar to the ones from this stack post.